# How to move the first line to the end of the file?

Tags: vi

How to delete the line after the first line that contains the pattern `invHn3ion?` and then move the first line to the end of the file?

Where can I learn all those expressions?

Comment: Do you need a script to do this, or do you need instructions of how to do this within `vi`?

Comment: a script will be nice. I just don't know much expressions.i only know how to delete lines matched the pattern in a file:g/pattern/d  but how about the lines AFTER the first matched line? and what about move the first line to the end of the file. Totally have no idea how to write cuz i never learn that before.

Comment: Maybe the professor doesn't spoon-feed you the answers to the homework because he expects you to be able to figure out how to read the manual.

Comment: he did not give any manual about these stuff

Comment: there is a wide held belief in the Linux/Unix world that if you teach a man to fish, he will fish for a while, then stop and forget how to fish, but if you throw a man a fishing pole and say "figure it out yourself" they will never forget how to fish for the rest of their life. Anyway, are you looking for a way of doing this inside `vi/vim` or looking for a way of writing a bash script that will edit a file automatically? You haven't given a lot of information really

Comment: It's unclear what the second mentioning of "the first line" refers to. I it line 1 of the text, or the line that matched `invHn3ion`, or is it a copy of the line that was deleted (which was mentioned first)?  This question needs an example text to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Some quicker/simpler keystrokes possible than this, but using my limited `vi` skills:

- Move to invHn3ion?

  ```
  /invHn3ion?
  ```
- Move down a line

  ```
  j
  ```
- Delete the line

  ```
  dd
  ```
- Move to first line

  ```
  1G
  ```
- Delete the line

  ```
  dd
  ```
- Move to end of file

  ```
  G
  ```
- Paste

  ```
  p
  ```
- Save

  ```
  ZZ
  ```

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that asks to copy the line containing `invHn3ion` (and it's hard to tell, but I guess that the `?` is part of the question, not part of the pattern).  And, since the question says "move the first line to the end of the file", deleting the first line (`1G`, `dd`) and pasting it at the end of the buffer (`G`, `p`) seems to be appropriate.  I don't see any reason to do a yank (`yy`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with something simpler. In the vi editor, to move the first line to the end, use the `ex` command `m` (move):

```
:1m$
```

The `1` argument is the source range: just the first line. You can use a range like `2,15m$` or a pattern match `/a.*bc/m$`. The destination `$` denotes the last line of the file.  The `m` command places the moved material **after** the target position.

There is no line zero, but the target 0 specifies the top of the file. So to move the line back to where it was:

```
:$m0
```

I.e. move the last line **after** the fictitious line zero (thus before line 1).

Okay, so how about moving the first line which matches the pattern `invHn3ion`?
Firstly we have consider that the current position could be anywhere. We want to start the search from the first line, not from the current position, thus:

```
:1/invHn3ion/m$
```

What's happening here is that `m` actually operates on the address argument `/invHn3ion/`. The `1` is a superfluous address which is evaluated and discarded<sup>1</sup>. We could get the same effect with two separate commands:

```
:1
:/invHn3ion/m$
```

The `m` command has a sibling `t` (transfer) which copies rather than moves.

---

1. See [Addressing in Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_02) section in the POSIX standard, starting with the paragraph "Commands take zero, one or two addresses ...".

Answer (score 0):

To move the very first line down to the very last line you can try with `sed` also

e.g.

```
$ sed -n '1p' file >> file && sed -i '1d' file
```

edit:

`$ sed -i '1h;1d;$G' file`

is an alternative GNU sed script. Note that the "-i" option is not available on Plan 9.

Answer (score 0):

With sed, the command is:

```
sed '/invHn3ion?/{h;d}; ${g}' FILE
```

and afaik, the sed syntax is very similar to the vi-Syntax.

Read it as /PATTERN/, if PATTERN is found, perform the commands h:=copy pattern to hold space, d:=delete the line. $, if not part of an regEx, denotes the last line of a file. So in the last line, g:=get content of hold space (and print it, the former saved pattern).

A tutorial about regular expressions with sed/awk/perl should teach you those. There are YT-Videos out there and books took, for vi/vim as well.